# Question on the IR and UV regions in the bulk?

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, conformal-field-theory, ads-cft

As the AdS/CFT correspondence is known, there is a correspondence between the quantum field theory and the string theory. Where do the duals of IR and UV place in the bulk? Are there the UV on the boundary and the IR near the horizon (or ‎$ r‎\rightarrow ‎0‎ $‎ )? Are these always true?
Do their places depend on the strong coupling and weak coupling?

Answer (score 3):

I'll use the coordinates where,
\begin{equation}
ds^2=\frac{L^2}{z^2}(dx^\mu dx_\mu-dz^2)
\end{equation}
The scale transformation of the Minkowski part $\tilde{x}^\mu=\lambda x^\mu$ can be converted into the isometry of the AdS spacetime if you also do $\tilde{z}=\lambda z$.

So you want to know what happens at very high energies. Then you take large $\lambda$ so with new coordinates you consider a very small region in terms of the old coordinates. In the bulk this corresponds to moving to very small $z$. I.e. the UV physics of QFT corresonds to the region near boundary. Likewise, you can see the inverse statement about IR